# How to decode json with different names in typed system and do custom parsing?

Tags: typescript

How can I specify/map json key to a different property name in typescript? e.g. I want to map payment-due in json to paymentDue in my type property.

Also, is there a way to parse e.g.

```
interest-due: {amount: "0", balance: "0"}
interest-income: {amount: "129", balance: "8551"}
```

into a generic Type like

```
const GenericType = t.type({
  name: t.string,
  amount: t.string,
  balance: t.string
});
```

and get an array of Generic with two elements which consists of interest-due and interest-income?

Comment: Why not alter the structure _after_ parsing the JSON instead of writing a custom parser?

Comment: I don’t know what the names in json are going to be e.g. interest-due, interest-income.